# Use of &body Lambda List Keyword in user-defined functions

Tags: clisp

There are a lot of examples of the web of `&body` being used in macros. It just can be accessed by `,@body` inside a backquote. But how do we use the `&body` lambda-list keyword in functions. I tried to make a number of functions using this keyword, but all they could return me was an error saying
`&BODY is not allowed in an ordinary lambda list: (&BODY PIKACHU)`
(well, my variable name was pikachu).

---

### Examples of tried functions :

```
 (defun tester (&body pikachu)
           (mapcar #'+ @pikachu))
```

Here, I used the `@` symbol in front of my `pikachu` because I thought that would make my `pikachu` into a list (not `raichu`). Well, that didn't happen, and I got the same error.
Another version :

```
(defun tester (&body pikachu)
           (mapcar #'+ pikachu))
```

This too, gave the same error.

---

And then according to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/tMgTi0Z_TzM), `&rest` and `&body` are approximately the same, `&rest` just takes a list, and `&body` takes an implicit `progn` of arguments.

And that clarified nothing to be honest. So, I would like to know how exactly `&body` works in lisp functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[&body](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dd.htm) is a *macro* lambda list element.
You can never use it in a function.
[&rest](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_da.htm) is to be used in ordinary functions for the same effect.

If you read the newsgroup thread you link to, you will see the same thing: the only difference between `&body` and `&rest` is the programmers intent conveyed to the reader.

PS. `@` is illegal outside of [backquote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_df.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I right if I say that `@` removes a pair of parenthesis from the result?(Inside a backquote, obviously)

Comment: @Mooncrater: yes, this is the right intuition. Please ask more specific questions separately, not in comments.